# PHP - Datetime to Standard String

Tags: php, datetime

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for through search.

Basically, I have a variable in PHP that echos:

```
2014-08-11 21:30:00
```

I would like it to instead echo:

```
August 11, 2014, 9:30PM
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is you current code?

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime http://php.net/date_format

Comment: [`DateTime::format()`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to output the date and `strtotime()` to parse the date string.

```
$time = strtotime("2014-08-11 21:30:00");
date("F d, Y, h:iA", $time);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/0YFQai7R

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime() to convert the time string into a format that date() needs:

```
$time = '2014-08-11 21:30:00';

echo date("F d, Y, h:iA", strtotime($time));
```